# Change TextChanged to not bubble in a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a custom RichTextBox control.

Part of this control is that it contains another RichTextBox (the ContentPresenter and the other RichTextbox are both shown by the control).

The problem I am having is that when the contained RichTextBox gets a TextChanged event it bubbles up to my control that is is holding it.  Making it look as if actual control had a text changed event.  (Instead of the contained RichTextBox.)

**Is there a way to make a RichTextBox that will not bubble its TextChanged RoutedEvents?**

Answer (score 0):

At the RichTextBox's TextChanged write this:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: I can do that, but the nature of the control has more than one handler of the TextChanged event.  I would rather not change that but if that is my only recourse, then I will.  However, I was hoping for a way to stop the bubbling.

Comment: My xaml for my custom control is quite large (over 200 lines).  What part do you want to see?  (Also, my setting up and handling of the TextChanged event happens in the C# not in the xaml.)